# How to align the text box in the same line?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble aligning two input boxes on the same line.

```
<div class="formHalf headForms  floatLeft" style="width: 55%;">
                        <label for="Payer Name" class="text inline" style="width: 80px">
                            Payer Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchValue1, new { @class = "text search", @style = "width: 56%;", tabindex = "1" })
                    </div>

                     <div class="formHalf headForms  floatLeft" style="width: 55%;">
                        <label for="Abbreviation" class="text inline" style="width: 80px">
                            Abbreviation </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchValue2, new { @class = "text search", @style = "width: 56%;", tabindex = "1" })
                    </div>
```

Comment: Could you show generated HTML code along with CSS to better understand what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="formHalf headForms  floatLeft inlineElements" style="width: 55%;">
       <label for="Payer Name" class="text inline" style="width: 80px">
              Payer Name
       </label>
       <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="formHalf headForms  floatLeft inlineElements" style="width: 55%;">
  <label for="Abbreviation" class="text inline" style="width: 80px">
                                Abbreviation </label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

css file:

```
.inlineElements {
    display: inline;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use { margin: 0 auto; } to align it in the center

Comment: 'on the same line' he said

Answer (score 0):

Use the [flexbox css property](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to do that

wrap your 'formHalf' divs inside another one. use these css properties to that 'wraping div'

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
```

Then refer to the guide

Answer (score 0):

see below code this should work for you

```css
.section {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.form-section {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-section">


  <div class="section">
      <label>name</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>name</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>

</div>
```